# Developing for sharepoint 2010 without it installed locally

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am currently looking into developing some WebParts for Microsoft Sharepoint 2010. I have set up a Windows 2008 Server virtual machine running Sharepoint 2010, and I have Visual Studio installed on my local machine (Windows 7 32 Bit).

However, it seems that I need to have Microsoft Sharepoint installed locally in order to access the templates in VS. I have found a couple of tutorials online saying you can develop Webparts locally without Sharepoint 2007 installed, but all 2010 tutorials insist on having Sharepoint installed locally.

Do the methods of deploying a sharepoint 2007 web part work under 2010, or alternatively, are there any good tutorials on how to develop a Sharepoint 2010 Web Part without having Sharepoint installed on the development machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a post [here](http://techblog.hk.agenda-asia.com/2010/10/29/create-sharepoint-project-without-install-sharepoint-server/) that describes what you are looking to do.  As Gavin mentioned below, you need to add the path to the registry.

Since you already have the VM on your local machine, my suggestion is to install a copy of Visual Studio installation there as well.  I have the same set-up with an instance of VS local for web development and one on my VM for SP development.

Comment: Rich - unfortunately the steps mentioned there do not work with Visual Studio 2010. :(

Comment: Is it more than just the paths to the dlls?  For 2010, these should be 14 instead of 12.

Comment: That was a comment left on the article you posted - however I have managed to get it working using another article - http://techblog.hk.agenda-asia.com/2010/10/29/create-sharepoint-project-without-install-sharepoint-server/ - you also need to add the path to the registry. I can now create and build projects from within VS

Comment: I changed the link and included your information from the above comment.  I also made this a community wiki since the answer was not mine but exists in the comments.  I think this closes the question too so it does not appear unanswered.

Comment: i'll accept the answer then, as it now provides a method that works in VS2010.